# Is there something missing

Tags: word-choice

It may take some trouble to make my point clear, but I would like to have a try.

The following is  two sentences in the speeches of Mr. Xi Jinping delivered on two different occassions.

今年是我提出“一带一路”倡议10周年，中方将举办第三届“一带一路”国际合作高峰论坛，欢迎各方参加论坛活动，共同把这条造福世界的幸福之路铺得更宽更远。

今年是我提出共建“一带一路”倡议十周年。这个倡议的根本出发点和落脚点，就是探索远亲近邻共同发展的新办法，开拓造福各国、惠及世界的“幸福路”。

I have noticed that for many times the project name "One Belt and One Road" is used interchangably as a name of place, hence the phrase 一带一路沿线国家.

However, if there is nothing wrong to use a phrase this way, it is awkward that a Belt, which is as important as the Road in the compound word, has been dropped when 幸福路 or 幸福之路 is only mentioned.

Similar case can also be found elsewhere. For example, 中国-东盟博览会 is shortened as 东博会 while 中国，or the counterpart of 东盟, is dropped, making it an expo of ASEAN only.

What is the problem of that? I'd like to hear your voice.

Comment: **roast** : isn’t there a proverb “garbage in, garbage out” 

Comment: 一带一路(政策的).....共同把这条造福世界的幸福(之)路铺得更宽更远..... (中国-)东(盟)博(览)会.... What is the question?

Comment: 你的中文比他好多了。哈哈。You are doing much better than him in speaking Mandaring.

Comment: 幸福之腰带？What about that?

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 Can you paraphrase the comment you gave?

Comment: @PdotWang We do not have to change the original meaning of the word Belt, how about幸福之带or 强国之带? Two things become one, it is not logical. LOL.

Comment: @r13 He or his secretary may have tried to play some game of words but regrettably has had part of the original meaning cut off. In the case of China-ASEAN Expo, it is very wrong that only one of the two parties is mentioned only becasue the two parties are as important as each other.

Comment: well, to grasp precisely the meaning of a communist’s propaganda is like, . . . finding what do one eat in vomit  we may find out, but the process is, . . . disgusting 

Answer (score 2):

> Why is "the Belt" dropped when 幸福路 or 幸福之路 is only mentioned?

Possibly for two reasons:

1. 一带一路 refers to 丝绸之路经济带 (The Silk Road Economic Belt) and 21世纪海上丝绸之路 (21st-Century Maritime Silk Road). Both concepts are in fact centered around "the silk road", but are given different names due to historical reasons. So using 幸福路 to refer to both is not a problem.
2. 道 and 路 can also mean the **direction of evolution over time** rather than just geographic concepts. In English it is the same: the way/path to success (通往成功之路). So 幸福路 here does not only mean the One Belt One Road regions, but also implies the initiative is a path leading to better welfare for people in these regions. Clearly, 带 does not have this meaning.

> Why is 中国-东盟博览会 shortened as 东博会？

Shortened names should follow the principle that it should contain enough information to suggest its original meaning, and 东博会 is definitely the best among a few alternatives:

1. 中东博会/中东会: Could be misunderstood as "the middle-east expo"
2. 中博会: Dropping 东盟 is not a good idea, as 东盟 is the main participant. But not mentioning China is ok since it is already held in China.

I don't think what you have observed is a phenomenon. These are just two very specific examples, happening due to very different reasons.